# Configuring mvc async task executor in springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to override the default task executor used by the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter bean in a SpringBoot/SpringMVC application.

The javadocs recommend to replace the use of the default but do not give any indication on how to do this nor can I find anything in the SpringBoot documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WebMvcConfigurer` has a callback for configuring async support (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.java#L92).

Comment: Thanks - worked,  I also found this article with code sample - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800842/spring-boot-any-shortcuts-for-setting-taskexecutor