# Springboot Warning! An Executor is required to handle java.util.concurrent.Callable

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-native-interface

I am running a Spring-Boot Service v2.3.5.RELEASE. Its an API that is very process intensive. It makes calls to **JNI->C++**. While making such an Execution I get the following warning:

> An Executor is required to handle java.util.concurrent.Callable return
> values. Please, configure a TaskExecutor in the MVC config under
> "async support". The SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor currently in use is not
> suitable under load.!!

Can such a warning ultimately lead to the microservice crashing?
And how to deal with this Warning?

Answer (score 0):

> Can such a warning ultimately lead to the microservice crashing?

"Under load", (rather) bet on it! ;) (Not the warning itself, but the fact complained)

> And how to deal with this Warning?

**When (we think) "load" is no issue, we *can* ignore the warning.** But the solution is not expensive:

see: [Asynchronous REST API generating warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52397752/592355)

> cite:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig  implements AsyncConfigurer {

  @Bean
  protected WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.setTaskExecutor(getTaskExecutor());
        }
    };
  }

  @Bean
  protected ConcurrentTaskExecutor getTaskExecutor() {
    return new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));
  }
}
```

Alternativeley we can configure any (for the warning to vanish: a non-trivial) `TaskExecutor` implementation.

See also:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using 2 `@Configuration` beans like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class MyApplicationConfiguration {
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setTaskExecutor(asyncTaskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor() {
        return new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));
    }
}
```